# multiple and dynamic Angular date picker

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I can't use multiple datepickers, loaded dynamically.

```html
<ng-container  *ngFor="let field of dateFields; let i = index">

  <mat-form-field class="fuse-mat-dense w-2/5 flex-grow">
    <input
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="field+i"
      type="date"
      [formControlName]="field+i"
     />
    <mat-hint>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle
      matIconSuffix
      [for]="field+i"
    ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #field+i></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

I can't find how to use a template ref of `#field+i` as a dynamic variable.

I´m working with these Angular dependencies:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/material-luxon-adapter": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "15.1.1",
    "rxjs": "7.8.0",
    "tslib": "2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "0.12.0"
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is using `FormArray`. Example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-component',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div formArrayName="fields">
        <div *ngFor="let field of fields.controls; let i = index">
          <mat-form-field
            class="fuse-mat-dense w-2/5 flex-grow">
            <input
              matInput
              [matDatepicker]="datepicker"
              [formControlName]="i"
            />
            <mat-hint>DD/MM/YYYY</mat-hint>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle
              matIconSuffix
              [for]="datepicker"
            ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #datepicker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  protected form = new FormGroup({
    fields: new FormArray<FormControl<Date | null>>([])
  })

  protected get fields() {
    return this.form.get('fields') as FormArray;
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.fields.push(new FormControl(null));
    }

    this.fields.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('One of the datepickers has changed value!')
      console.log(this.fields.value);
    });
  }

}
```